# SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/php-fpm from lock access on the file cert9.db

Tags: rhel, security, php, selinux

I have an selinux alert for the file `/var/cache/nginx/.pki/nssdb/cert9.db.`, but I don't know what label I should give to it. The selinux report suggests hundreds of labels, but which is the correct one to allow php-fpm to have lock access on the cert9.db file?

```
SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/php-fpm from lock access on the file /var/cache/nginx/.pki/nssdb/cert9.db.

*****  Plugin catchall_labels (83.8 confidence) suggests   *******************

If you want to allow php-fpm to have lock access on the cert9.db file
Then you need to change the label on /var/cache/nginx/.pki/nssdb/cert9.db
Do
# semanage fcontext -a -t FILE_TYPE '/var/cache/nginx/.pki/nssdb/cert9.db'
where FILE_TYPE is one of the following: NetworkManager_exec_t, NetworkManager_log_t, NetworkManager_tmp_t, abrt_dump_oops_exec_t, abrt_etc_t, abrt_exec_t, abrt_handle_event_exec_t, abrt_helper_exec_t, abrt_retrace_coredump_exec_t, abrt_retrace_spool_t, abrt_retrace_worker_exec_t, abrt_tmp_t, abrt_upload_watch_tmp_t, abrt_var_cache_t, abrt_var_log_t, abrt_var_run_t, accountsd_exec_t, acct_data_t, acct_exec_t, admin_crontab_tmp_t, admin_passwd_exec_t, afs_logfile_t, aide_exec_t, aide_log_t, alsa_exec_t, alsa_tmp_t, amanda_exec_t, amanda_log_t, amanda_recover_exec_t, amanda_tmp_t, amtu_exec_t, anacron_exec_t, anon_inodefs_t, antivirus_log_t, antivirus_tmp_t, apcupsd_cgi_content_t, apcupsd_cgi_htaccess_t, apcupsd_cgi_ra_content_t, apcupsd_cgi_rw_content_t, apcupsd_cgi_script_exec_t, apcupsd_log_t, apcupsd_tmp_t, apm_exec_t, apmd_log_t, apmd_tmp_t, arpwatch_tmp_t, asterisk_log_t, asterisk_tmp_t, audisp_exec_t, auditadm_sudo_tmp_t, auditctl_exec_t, auth_cache_t, authconfig_exec_t, automount_tmp_t, avahi_exec_t, awstats_content_t, awstats_htaccess_t, awstats_ra_content_t, awstats_rw_content_t, awstats_script_exec_t, awstats_tmp_t, bacula_admin_exec_t, bacula_log_t, bacula_tmp_t, bacula_unconfined_script_exec_t, bin_t, bitlbee_log_t, bitlbee_tmp_t, blueman_exec_t, bluetooth_helper_exec_t, bluetooth_helper_tmp_t, bluetooth_helper_tmpfs_t, bluetooth_tmp_t, boinc_log_t, boinc_project_tmp_t, boinc_tmp_t, boot_t, bootloader_exec_t, bootloader_tmp_t, brctl_exec_t, brltty_log_t, bugzilla_content_t, bugzilla_htaccess_t, bugzilla_ra_content_t, bugzilla_rw_content_t, bugzilla_script_exec_t, bugzilla_tmp_t, calamaris_exec_t, calamaris_log_t, calamaris_www_t, callweaver_log_t, canna_log_t, cardctl_exec_t, cardmgr_dev_t, ccs_tmp_t, ccs_var_lib_t, ccs_var_log_t, cdcc_exec_t, cdcc_tmp_t, cdrecord_exec_t, cert_t, certmaster_var_log_t, certmonger_unconfined_exec_t, certwatch_exec_t, cfengine_log_t, cgred_log_t, checkpc_exec_t, checkpc_log_t, checkpolicy_exec_t, chfn_exec_t, chkpwd_exec_t, chrome_sandbox_exec_t, chrome_sandbox_nacl_exec_t, chrome_sandbox_tmp_t, chronyc_exec_t, chronyd_tmp_t, chronyd_var_log_t, cinder_api_tmp_t, cinder_backup_tmp_t, cinder_log_t, cinder_scheduler_tmp_t, cinder_volume_tmp_t, cloud_init_tmp_t, cloud_log_t, cluster_conf_t, cluster_tmp_t, cluster_var_lib_t, cluster_var_log_t, cluster_var_run_t, cobbler_etc_t, cobbler_tmp_t, cobbler_var_lib_t, cobbler_var_log_t, cockpit_tmp_t, collectd_content_t, collectd_htaccess_t, collectd_ra_content_t, collectd_rw_content_t, collectd_script_exec_t, collectd_script_tmp_t, colord_exec_t, colord_tmp_t, comsat_tmp_t, condor_log_t, condor_master_tmp_t, condor_schedd_tmp_t, condor_startd_tmp_t, conman_log_t, conman_tmp_t, conman_unconfined_script_exec_t, consolehelper_exec_t, consolekit_exec_t, consolekit_log_t, container_log_t, container_runtime_tmp_t, couchdb_log_t, couchdb_tmp_t, courier_exec_t, cpu_online_t, cpucontrol_exec_t, cpufreqselector_exec_t, cpuspeed_exec_t, crack_exec_t, crack_tmp_t, cron_log_t, crond_tmp_t, crontab_exec_t, crontab_tmp_t, ctdbd_log_t, ctdbd_tmp_t, cups_pdf_tmp_t, cupsd_config_exec_t, cupsd_log_t, cupsd_lpd_tmp_t, cupsd_tmp_t, cvs_content_t, cvs_data_t, cvs_exec_t, cvs_htaccess_t, cvs_ra_content_t, cvs_rw_content_t, cvs_script_exec_t, cvs_tmp_t, cyphesis_exec_t, cyphesis_log_t, cyphesis_tmp_t, cyrus_tmp_t, dbadm_sudo_tmp_t, dbskkd_tmp_t, dbusd_etc_t, dbusd_exec_t, dcc_client_exec_t, dcc_client_tmp_t, dcc_dbclean_exec_t, dcc_dbclean_tmp_t, dccd_tmp_t, dccifd_tmp_t, dccm_tmp_t, ddclient_log_t, ddclient_tmp_t, debuginfo_exec_t, deltacloudd_log_t, deltacloudd_tmp_t, denyhosts_var_log_t, depmod_exec_t, devicekit_disk_exec_t, devicekit_exec_t, devicekit_power_exec_t, devicekit_tmp_t, devicekit_var_log_t, dhcpc_exec_t, dhcpc_tmp_t, dhcpd_tmp_t, dirsrv_config_t, dirsrv_share_t, dirsrv_snmp_var_log_t, dirsrv_tmp_t, dirsrv_var_log_t, dirsrv_var_run_t, dirsrvadmin_config_t, dirsrvadmin_content_t, dirsrvadmin_htaccess_t, dirsrvadmin_ra_content_t, dirsrvadmin_rw_content_t, dirsrvadmin_script_exec_t, dirsrvadmin_tmp_t, disk_munin_plugin_exec_t, disk_munin_plugin_tmp_t, dkim_milter_tmp_t, dlm_controld_var_log_t, dmesg_exec_t, dmidecode_exec_t, dnsmasq_tmp_t, dnsmasq_var_log_t, dnssec_trigger_tmp_t, dovecot_auth_tmp_t, dovecot_deliver_tmp_t, dovecot_tmp_t, dovecot_var_log_t, drbd_tmp_t, dspam_content_t, dspam_htaccess_t, dspam_log_t, dspam_ra_content_t, dspam_rw_content_t, dspam_script_exec_t, etc_runtime_t, etc_t, evtchnd_var_log_t, exim_exec_t, exim_log_t, exim_tmp_t, fail2ban_client_exec_t, fail2ban_log_t, fail2ban_tmp_t, fail2ban_var_lib_t, faillog_t, fenced_tmp_t, fenced_var_log_t, fetchmail_exec_t, fetchmail_log_t, file_context_t, fingerd_log_t, firewalld_exec_t, firewalld_tmp_t, firewalld_var_log_t, firewallgui_exec_t, firewallgui_tmp_t, firstboot_exec_t, foghorn_var_log_t, fonts_cache_t, fonts_t, fprintd_exec_t, freqset_exec_t, fsadm_exec_t, fsadm_log_t, fsadm_tmp_t, fsdaemon_tmp_t, ftpd_tmp_t, ftpdctl_exec_t, ftpdctl_tmp_t, games_exec_t, games_tmp_t, games_tmpfs_t, ganesha_tmp_t, ganesha_var_log_t, gconf_tmp_t, gconfd_exec_t, gconfdefaultsm_exec_t, geoclue_exec_t, geoclue_tmp_t, getty_exec_t, getty_log_t, getty_tmp_t, gfs_controld_var_log_t, git_content_t, git_htaccess_t, git_ra_content_t, git_rw_content_t, git_script_exec_t, git_script_tmp_t, git_sys_content_t, gitd_exec_t, gitosis_exec_t, gitosis_var_lib_t, gkeyringd_exec_t, gkeyringd_tmp_t, glance_log_t, glance_registry_tmp_t, glance_tmp_t, glusterd_log_t, glusterd_tmp_t, gnomesystemmm_exec_t, gpg_agent_exec_t, gpg_agent_tmp_t, gpg_exec_t, gpg_helper_exec_t, gpg_pinentry_tmp_t, gpg_pinentry_tmpfs_t, gpm_tmp_t, gpsd_exec_t, groupadd_exec_t, groupd_var_log_t, gssd_tmp_t, haproxy_var_log_t, hostname_etc_t, hostname_exec_t, hsqldb_tmp_t, httpd_cache_t, httpd_config_t, httpd_exec_t, httpd_keytab_t, httpd_lock_t, httpd_log_t, httpd_modules_t, httpd_passwd_exec_t, httpd_php_tmp_t, httpd_squirrelmail_t, httpd_suexec_tmp_t, httpd_sys_content_t, httpd_sys_htaccess_t, httpd_sys_ra_content_t, httpd_sys_rw_content_t, httpd_sys_script_exec_t, httpd_tmp_t, httpd_tmpfs_t, httpd_user_htaccess_t, httpd_user_ra_content_t, httpd_user_rw_content_t, httpd_user_script_exec_t, httpd_var_lib_t, httpd_var_run_t, hugetlbfs_t, hwclock_exec_t, hwloc_dhwd_exec_t, iceauth_exec_t, icecast_exec_t, icecast_log_t, ifconfig_exec_t, inetd_child_tmp_t, inetd_log_t, inetd_tmp_t, init_tmp_t, initrc_tmp_t, initrc_var_log_t, innd_log_t, insmod_exec_t, install_exec_t, iotop_exec_t, ipa_cert_t, ipa_helper_exec_t, ipa_log_t, ipa_tmp_t, ipa_var_lib_t, ipa_var_run_t, ipsec_log_t, ipsec_mgmt_exec_t, ipsec_tmp_t, iptables_exec_t, iptables_tmp_t, irc_exec_t, irssi_exec_t, iscsi_log_t, iscsi_tmp_t, iso9660_t, iwhd_log_t, jetty_cache_t, jetty_log_t, jetty_var_lib_t, jetty_var_run_t, jockey_exec_t, jockey_var_log_t, journalctl_exec_t, kadmind_log_t, kadmind_tmp_t, kdump_exec_t, kdumpctl_tmp_t, kdumpgui_exec_t, kdumpgui_tmp_t, keepalived_unconfined_script_exec_t, keystone_cgi_content_t, keystone_cgi_htaccess_t, keystone_cgi_ra_content_t, keystone_cgi_rw_content_t, keystone_cgi_script_exec_t, keystone_log_t, keystone_tmp_t, kismet_exec_t, kismet_log_t, kismet_tmp_t, kismet_tmpfs_t, klogd_tmp_t, krb5_conf_t, krb5_host_rcache_t, krb5_keytab_t, krb5kdc_conf_t, krb5kdc_log_t, krb5kdc_tmp_t, ksmtuned_log_t, ktalkd_log_t, ktalkd_tmp_t, l2tpd_tmp_t, lastlog_t, ld_so_cache_t, ldconfig_exec_t, ldconfig_tmp_t, lib_t, livecd_exec_t, livecd_tmp_t, load_policy_exec_t, loadkeys_exec_t, locale_t, locate_exec_t, lockdev_exec_t, login_exec_t, logrotate_mail_tmp_t, logrotate_tmp_t, logwatch_exec_t, logwatch_mail_tmp_t, logwatch_tmp_t, lpd_tmp_t, lpr_exec_t, lpr_tmp_t, lsassd_tmp_t, lsmd_plugin_exec_t, lsmd_plugin_tmp_t, lvm_exec_t, lvm_tmp_t, machineid_t, mail_munin_plugin_exec_t, mail_munin_plugin_tmp_t, mailman_archive_t, mailman_cgi_tmp_t, mailman_data_t, mailman_log_t, mailman_mail_tmp_t, mailman_queue_tmp_t, man2html_content_t, man2html_htaccess_t, man2html_ra_content_t, man2html_rw_content_t, man2html_script_exec_t, man_cache_t, man_t, mandb_cache_t, mcelog_exec_t, mcelog_log_t, mdadm_log_t, mdadm_tmp_t, mediawiki_content_t, mediawiki_htaccess_t, mediawiki_ra_content_t, mediawiki_rw_content_t, mediawiki_script_exec_t, mediawiki_tmp_t, mencoder_exec_t, minidlna_log_t, mirrormanager_exec_t, mirrormanager_log_t, mirrormanager_var_lib_t, mirrormanager_var_run_t, mock_build_exec_t, mock_exec_t, mock_tmp_t, modemmanager_exec_t, mojomojo_content_t, mojomojo_htaccess_t, mojomojo_ra_content_t, mojomojo_rw_content_t, mojomojo_script_exec_t, mojomojo_tmp_t, mongod_log_t, mongod_tmp_t, motion_log_t, mount_ecryptfs_exec_t, mount_exec_t, mount_tmp_t, mozilla_exec_t, mozilla_plugin_config_exec_t, mozilla_plugin_exec_t, mozilla_plugin_tmp_t, mozilla_plugin_tmpfs_t, mozilla_tmp_t, mozilla_tmpfs_t, mpd_exec_t, mpd_log_t, mpd_tmp_t, mplayer_exec_t, mplayer_tmpfs_t, mrtg_exec_t, mrtg_log_t, mscan_tmp_t, munin_content_t, munin_etc_t, munin_htaccess_t, munin_log_t, munin_ra_content_t, munin_rw_content_t, munin_script_exec_t, munin_script_tmp_t, munin_tmp_t, mysqld_etc_t, mysqld_log_t, mysqld_tmp_t, mythtv_content_t, mythtv_htaccess_t, mythtv_ra_content_t, mythtv_rw_content_t, mythtv_script_exec_t, mythtv_var_log_t, nagios_admin_plugin_exec_t, nagios_checkdisk_plugin_exec_t, nagios_content_t, nagios_etc_t, nagios_eventhandler_plugin_exec_t, nagios_eventhandler_plugin_tmp_t, nagios_htaccess_t, nagios_log_t, nagios_mail_plugin_exec_t, nagios_openshift_plugin_exec_t, nagios_openshift_plugin_tmp_t, nagios_ra_content_t, nagios_rw_content_t, nagios_script_exec_t, nagios_services_plugin_exec_t, nagios_system_plugin_exec_t, nagios_system_plugin_tmp_t, nagios_tmp_t, nagios_unconfined_plugin_exec_t, nagios_var_lib_t, named_checkconf_exec_t, named_exec_t, named_log_t, named_tmp_t, namespace_init_exec_t, ncftool_exec_t, ndc_exec_t, net_conf_t, netlabel_mgmt_exec_t, netutils_exec_t, netutils_tmp_t, neutron_log_t, neutron_tmp_t, newrole_exec_t, nova_log_t, nova_tmp_t, nscd_log_t, nsd_log_t, nsd_tmp_t, ntop_tmp_t, ntpd_log_t, ntpd_tmp_t, ntpdate_exec_t, numad_var_log_t, nut_upsd_tmp_t, nut_upsdrvctl_tmp_t, nut_upsmon_tmp_t, nutups_cgi_content_t, nutups_cgi_htaccess_t, nutups_cgi_ra_content_t, nutups_cgi_rw_content_t, nutups_cgi_script_exec_t, nx_server_tmp_t, obex_exec_t, oddjob_mkhomedir_exec_t, opendnssec_tmp_t, openhpid_log_t, openshift_cgroup_read_exec_t, openshift_cgroup_read_tmp_t, openshift_content_t, openshift_cron_tmp_t, openshift_htaccess_t, openshift_initrc_tmp_t, openshift_log_t, openshift_net_read_exec_t, openshift_ra_content_t, openshift_rw_content_t, openshift_script_exec_t, openshift_tmp_t, opensm_log_t, openvpn_status_t, openvpn_tmp_t, openvpn_var_log_t, openvswitch_log_t, openvswitch_tmp_t, openwsman_log_t, openwsman_tmp_t, oracleasm_tmp_t, osad_log_t, pads_exec_t, pam_console_exec_t, pam_timestamp_tmp_t, passenger_exec_t, passenger_log_t, passenger_tmp_t, passenger_var_lib_t, passenger_var_run_t, passwd_exec_t, passwd_file_t, pcp_log_t, pcp_tmp_t, pcscd_var_run_t, pegasus_openlmi_storage_tmp_t, pegasus_tmp_t, pesign_tmp_t, pinentry_exec_t, ping_exec_t, piranha_log_t, piranha_web_tmp_t, pkcs_slotd_log_t, pkcs_slotd_tmp_t, pki_log_t, pki_ra_etc_rw_t, pki_ra_log_t, pki_ra_var_lib_t, pki_ra_var_run_t, pki_tomcat_cert_t, pki_tomcat_log_t, pki_tomcat_tmp_t, pki_tps_etc_rw_t, pki_tps_log_t, pki_tps_var_lib_t, pki_tps_var_run_t, plymouth_exec_t, plymouthd_var_log_t, podsleuth_exec_t, podsleuth_tmp_t, podsleuth_tmpfs_t, policykit_auth_exec_t, policykit_exec_t, policykit_grant_exec_t, policykit_resolve_exec_t, policykit_tmp_t, polipo_exec_t, polipo_log_t, portmap_helper_exec_t, portmap_tmp_t, postfix_bounce_tmp_t, postfix_cleanup_tmp_t, postfix_exec_t, postfix_local_tmp_t, postfix_map_exec_t, postfix_map_tmp_t, postfix_pickup_tmp_t, postfix_pipe_tmp_t, postfix_postdrop_exec_t, postfix_postdrop_t, postfix_postqueue_exec_t, postfix_qmgr_tmp_t, postfix_showq_exec_t, postfix_smtp_tmp_t, postfix_smtpd_tmp_t, postfix_virtual_tmp_t, postgresql_log_t, postgresql_tmp_t, pppd_exec_t, pppd_log_t, pppd_tmp_t, pptp_log_t, prelink_exec_t, prelink_log_t, prelink_tmp_t, prelude_lml_tmp_t, prelude_log_t, preupgrade_data_t, preupgrade_exec_t, prewikka_content_t, prewikka_htaccess_t, prewikka_ra_content_t, prewikka_rw_content_t, prewikka_script_exec_t, privoxy_log_t, proc_t, procmail_exec_t, procmail_log_t, procmail_tmp_t, prosody_log_t, prosody_tmp_t, psad_tmp_t, psad_var_log_t, ptchown_exec_t, public_content_rw_t, public_content_t, pulseaudio_exec_t, pulseaudio_tmpfs_t, puppet_log_t, puppet_tmp_t, puppet_var_lib_t, puppetca_exec_t, puppetmaster_tmp_t, pwauth_exec_t, pyicqt_log_t, qdiskd_var_log_t, qemu_exec_t, qmail_tcp_env_exec_t, qpidd_tmp_t, quota_exec_t, rabbitmq_tmp_t, rabbitmq_var_log_t, racoon_tmp_t, radiusd_log_t, readahead_exec_t, realmd_exec_t, realmd_tmp_t, realmd_var_lib_t, redis_log_t, rhev_agentd_log_t, rhev_agentd_tmp_t, rhsmcertd_exec_t, rhsmcertd_log_t, rhsmcertd_tmp_t, ricci_modcluster_var_log_t, ricci_tmp_t, ricci_var_log_t, rkhunter_var_lib_t, rlogind_tmp_t, rpcbind_tmp_t, rpm_exec_t, rpm_log_t, rpm_script_tmp_t, rpm_tmp_t, rssh_chroot_helper_exec_t, rssh_exec_t, rsync_exec_t, rsync_log_t, rsync_tmp_t, rtas_errd_log_t, rtas_errd_tmp_t, rtkit_daemon_exec_t, run_init_exec_t, samba_etc_t, samba_log_t, samba_net_exec_t, samba_net_tmp_t, samba_var_t, sambagui_exec_t, sanlock_log_t, sbd_tmpfs_t, sblim_tmp_t, screen_exec_t, secadm_sudo_tmp_t, sectool_tmp_t, sectool_var_log_t, sectoolm_exec_t, security_t, selinux_munin_plugin_exec_t, selinux_munin_plugin_tmp_t, semanage_exec_t, semanage_tmp_t, sendmail_exec_t, sendmail_log_t, sendmail_tmp_t, sensord_log_t, services_munin_plugin_exec_t, services_munin_plugin_tmp_t, session_dbusd_tmp_t, setfiles_exec_t, setkey_exec_t, setroubleshoot_fixit_exec_t, setroubleshoot_var_log_t, setroubleshootd_exec_t, setsebool_exec_t, seunshare_exec_t, sge_job_exec_t, sge_shepherd_exec_t, sge_tmp_t, shell_exec_t, shorewall_log_t, shorewall_tmp_t, showmount_exec_t, slapd_cert_t, slapd_log_t, slapd_tmp_t, slpd_log_t, smbcontrol_exec_t, smbd_tmp_t, smokeping_cgi_content_t, smokeping_cgi_htaccess_t, smokeping_cgi_ra_content_t, smokeping_cgi_rw_content_t, smokeping_cgi_script_exec_t, smokeping_var_lib_t, smokeping_var_run_t, smoltclient_exec_t, smoltclient_tmp_t, smsd_log_t, smsd_tmp_t, snapperd_exec_t, snapperd_log_t, snmpd_log_t, snort_log_t, snort_tmp_t, sosreport_exec_t, sosreport_tmp_t, soundd_tmp_t, spamc_exec_t, spamc_tmp_t, spamd_log_t, spamd_tmp_t, spamd_update_exec_t, speech-dispatcher_exec_t, speech-dispatcher_log_t, speech-dispatcher_tmp_t, squid_content_t, squid_cron_exec_t, squid_htaccess_t, squid_log_t, squid_ra_content_t, squid_rw_content_t, squid_script_exec_t, squid_tmp_t, squirrelmail_spool_t, src_t, ssh_agent_exec_t, ssh_agent_tmp_t, ssh_exec_t, ssh_keygen_exec_t, ssh_keygen_tmp_t, ssh_keysign_exec_t, ssh_tmpfs_t, sssd_public_t, sssd_selinux_manager_exec_t, sssd_var_lib_t, sssd_var_log_t, staff_sudo_tmp_t, stapserver_log_t, stapserver_tmp_t, stunnel_log_t, stunnel_tmp_t, su_exec_t, sudo_exec_t, sudo_log_t, sulogin_exec_t, svc_multilog_exec_t, svc_run_exec_t, svc_start_exec_t, svirt_tmp_t, svnserve_log_t, svnserve_tmp_t, swat_tmp_t, swift_tmp_t, sysadm_passwd_tmp_t, sysadm_sudo_tmp_t, sysfs_t, syslogd_tmp_t, sysstat_exec_t, sysstat_log_t, system_conf_t, system_cronjob_tmp_t, system_db_t, system_dbusd_tmp_t, system_dbusd_var_lib_t, system_mail_tmp_t, system_munin_plugin_exec_t, system_munin_plugin_tmp_t, systemd_passwd_var_run_t, targetd_tmp_t, tcpd_tmp_t, telepathy_gabble_exec_t, telepathy_gabble_tmp_t, telepathy_idle_exec_t, telepathy_idle_tmp_t, telepathy_logger_exec_t, telepathy_logger_tmp_t, telepathy_mission_control_exec_t, telepathy_mission_control_tmp_t, telepathy_msn_exec_t, telepathy_msn_tmp_t, telepathy_salut_exec_t, telepathy_salut_tmp_t, telepathy_sofiasip_exec_t, telepathy_sofiasip_tmp_t, telepathy_stream_engine_exec_t, telepathy_stream_engine_tmp_t, telepathy_sunshine_exec_t, telepathy_sunshine_tmp_t, telnetd_tmp_t, tetex_data_t, textrel_shlib_t, tgtd_tmp_t, thin_aeolus_configserver_log_t, thin_log_t, thumb_exec_t, thumb_tmp_t, tmp_t, tmpreaper_exec_t, tomcat_log_t, tomcat_tmp_t, tor_var_log_t, traceroute_exec_t, tuned_log_t, tuned_tmp_t, tvtime_exec_t, tvtime_tmp_t, tvtime_tmpfs_t, udev_tmp_t, udev_var_run_t, ulogd_var_log_t, uml_exec_t, uml_tmp_t, uml_tmpfs_t, unconfined_exec_t, unconfined_munin_plugin_exec_t, unconfined_munin_plugin_tmp_t, update_modules_exec_t, update_modules_tmp_t, updfstab_exec_t, usbmodules_exec_t, usbmuxd_exec_t, user_cron_spool_t, user_fonts_t, user_mail_tmp_t, user_tmp_t, useradd_exec_t, userhelper_exec_t, usernetctl_exec_t, usr_t, utempter_exec_t, uucpd_log_t, uucpd_tmp_t, uux_exec_t, var_lib_t, var_log_t, var_spool_t, varnishd_tmp_t, varnishlog_log_t, vdagent_log_t, virsh_exec_t, virt_log_t, virt_qemu_ga_log_t, virt_qemu_ga_tmp_t, virt_qemu_ga_unconfined_exec_t, virt_tmp_t, virt_var_lib_t, virtd_lxc_exec_t, vlock_exec_t, vmtools_helper_exec_t, vmtools_tmp_t, vmtools_unconfined_exec_t, vmware_exec_t, vmware_host_tmp_t, vmware_log_t, vmware_tmp_t, vmware_tmpfs_t, vnstat_exec_t, vpnc_exec_t, vpnc_tmp_t, w3c_validator_content_t, w3c_validator_htaccess_t, w3c_validator_ra_content_t, w3c_validator_rw_content_t, w3c_validator_script_exec_t, w3c_validator_tmp_t, watchdog_log_t, watchdog_unconfined_exec_t, webadm_tmp_t, webalizer_content_t, webalizer_exec_t, webalizer_htaccess_t, webalizer_ra_content_t, webalizer_rw_content_t, webalizer_script_exec_t, webalizer_tmp_t, winbind_log_t, wine_exec_t, wireshark_exec_t, wireshark_tmp_t, wireshark_tmpfs_t, wpa_cli_exec_t, wtmp_t, xauth_exec_t, xauth_tmp_t, xdm_exec_t, xdm_log_t, xdm_unconfined_exec_t, xend_tmp_t, xend_var_log_t, xenstored_tmp_t, xenstored_var_log_t, xferlog_t, xserver_exec_t, xserver_log_t, xserver_tmpfs_t, ypbind_tmp_t, ypserv_tmp_t, zabbix_log_t, zabbix_script_exec_t, zabbix_tmp_t, zarafa_deliver_log_t, zarafa_deliver_tmp_t, zarafa_gateway_log_t, zarafa_ical_log_t, zarafa_indexer_log_t, zarafa_indexer_tmp_t, zarafa_monitor_log_t, zarafa_server_log_t, zarafa_server_tmp_t, zarafa_spooler_log_t, zarafa_var_lib_t, zebra_log_t, zebra_tmp_t, zoneminder_content_t, zoneminder_exec_t, zoneminder_htaccess_t, zoneminder_log_t, zoneminder_ra_content_t, zoneminder_rw_content_t, zoneminder_script_exec_t, zoneminder_var_lib_t, zos_remote_exec_t.
Then execute:
restorecon -v '/var/cache/nginx/.pki/nssdb/cert9.db'


*****  Plugin catchall (17.1 confidence) suggests   **************************

If you believe that php-fpm should be allowed lock access on the cert9.db file by default.
Then you should report this as a bug.
You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
Do
allow this access for now by executing:
# ausearch -c 'php-fpm' --raw | audit2allow -M my-phpfpm
# semodule -i my-phpfpm.pp


Additional Information:
Source Context                system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
Target Context                system_u:object_r:var_t:s0
Target Objects                /var/cache/nginx/.pki/nssdb/cert9.db [ file ]
Source                        php-fpm
Source Path                   /usr/sbin/php-fpm
Port                          <Unknown>
Host                          di-staging
Source RPM Packages           php-fpm-7.2.14-1.el7.remi.x86_64
Target RPM Packages
Policy RPM                    selinux-policy-3.13.1-229.el7_6.6.noarch
Selinux Enabled               True
Policy Type                   targeted
Enforcing Mode                Enforcing
Host Name                     di-staging
Platform                      Linux di-staging 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu
                              Nov 8 23:39:32 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64
Alert Count                   936
First Seen                    2019-03-02 16:32:29 GMT
Last Seen                     2019-03-02 21:24:14 GMT
Local ID                      3a672c0c-ed3b-4509-9695-49eca37e2061

Raw Audit Messages
type=AVC msg=audit(1551561854.609:568178): avc:  denied  { lock } for  pid=3751 comm="php-fpm" path="/var/cache/nginx/.pki/nssdb/cert9.db" dev="sda2" ino=790407 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:var_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0


type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1551561854.609:568178): arch=x86_64 syscall=fcntl success=no exit=EACCES a0=8 a1=6 a2=7ffe4a3e47e0 a3=0 items=0 ppid=3450 pid=3751 auid=4294967295 uid=996 gid=993 euid=996 suid=996 fsuid=996 egid=993 sgid=993 fsgid=993 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm=php-fpm exe=/usr/sbin/php-fpm subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)

Hash: php-fpm,httpd_t,var_t,file,lock
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `php-fpm` process is running under an `httpd_t` context (more specifically, `scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0`), so if you're considering changing the context of the `cert9.db` file, you might want to use one of the `httpd_*` types.

Of those types, two look like they might be close matches: `httpd_cache_t`, since the file is under `/var/cache`, or `httpd_var_lib_t`, since `/var/lib` is quite similar to `/var/cache` in many regards. So you might want to consider giving these two a try, seeing if they do indeed fix your problem and if they don't seem to introduce any other issues or unwanted side effects.

I guess the proper answer to this issue requires taking a closer look at the SELinux policy, what the role of the `cert9.db` file and its contents and what `php-fpm` is doing with it... If you have a subscription to RHEL, consider opening an issue with Red Hat asking them to weigh in on what the appropriate solution to this issue is, you might get a better answer from them.

Comment: thanks setting it to `httpd_cache_t` seems to have done the trick.